# Connect MongoDB to Tableau or Microsoft Power BI for real-time analysis

Tags: mongodb, microsoft-powerbi, tableau

I have a website whose database is MongoDB, I want to track KPIs and analyse them in real-time. I am thinking of Tableau and Microsoft Power BI. But I have not found how to connect MongoDB to them in real-time.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

If you are set on using Tableau or Power BI, a supported option developed by MongoDB is the [MongoDB Connector for BI](https://www.mongodb.com/products/bi-connector). This is a commercial tool (licensed as part of a MongoDB Enterprise Advanced subscription) which provides a SQL proxy interface to your MongoDB deployment using the MySQL protocol.

If you are open to considering other BI tools, there are some that have direct support for MongoDB such as [Jasper Reports](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/mongodb), [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/analytics-for-mongodb), and [JSON Studio](http://jsonstudio.com/bi-mongodb/).

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using other BI tools which support MongoDB there are several options:

1. KoolReport [https://www.koolreport.com]
2. JasperReport [https://www.jaspersoft.com]
3. slamdata [https://www.simba.com]
4. Pentaho [http://www.pentaho.com/analytics-for-mongodb]

If you need to use Tableau or Power BI then the MongoDB Connector for BI is the best option.

Regardless of what tool you use, Mongo has recommendations for [ETL](https://blog.panoply.io/etl-vs-elt-the-difference-is-in-the-how)/ELT or analytic processes with their product:

1. Connections: connect using the standard URI string. Connection options include to a Mongo process, to a Mongo replica set or to Mongo as a cluster frontend.
2. The application should warn users of queries without indexed fields before execution and allow users to modify the query.
3. If using a MongoDB shared cluster, it is strongly recommended not to run queries with poor query isolation. Running such queries will negatively impact DB performance.